# Math oriented French

Tags: mathématiques

For a graduate student majored in mathematics, how to self-study French so that one can read textbooks or papers written in French? More specifically, one of my goals is to be able to read [Éléments de géométrie algébrique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89l%C3%A9ments_de_g%C3%A9om%C3%A9trie_alg%C3%A9brique) or [Éléments de mathématique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89l%C3%A9ments_de_math%C3%A9matique) (aside from apprehending there math part, of course).

Comment: New to the community, sorry if this is not the type of questions concerned here.

Comment: I'm not a mathematician, but from I've gathered of Grothendieck's works  and the EGA  you'd need to master any language related to Bourbaki's terminology which would probably be the easiest part. As far as  French language is concerned it is not literary French of corse, but still you'd need to grasp quite a lot, not only simple sentences.  Haven't the EGA been translated into English?

Comment: There is no  better way for doing that, than sweating it out; by that I mean buying a variety of elementary texts in French and gradually more complex texts and studying them and their vocabulary. The problem with Bourbaki's set theory is that it is  not any more the only reference in set theory, and its vocabulary is particular to Bourbaki in many cases; French writers in the domain of so called Modern Mathematics tend nowadays to follow Anglo-Saxon terminology and strict Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory (see for instance _Logique mathématique_ by René Cori and Daniel Lascar).

Comment: This is not really the best place to ask the question, it could be asked on [Language Learning](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/) but I expect  [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) would be better since there's bound to be members who've read those in French and/or in English. It seems some volumes of the *Éléments de Mathématiques*  have been translated into English (wikipedia link) and I've come upon [Is an English translation of Grothendieck's EGA available?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/31647) on MathsOverflow.

Comment: Specialized language as used in math is a **subset** of the language. Just get a grammar book with good exercises.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about language learning.

Comment: @None Thanks for the advice and information! Some of Grothendieck’s other work seems to have no English version available online but sometimes I‘ll encounter them searching bibliography from elsewhere. And as the field of study gets deeper, many French written references just come into sight, so I’d like to learn French systematically to deal with them all. I will work my way through. Sorry for the delay in reply(didn’t know if I can turn on notifications or something).

Comment: @LPH Many thanks to the advice. My aim was strongly pragmatic, but maybe there is no crash course for language. The mentioning of Bourbaki’s work was just an example, and frankly speaking I found their approach to algebra (especially homological algebra and commutative algebra) quite illuminating, even from a modern view, so would like to pick it as a reference.

Comment: @Lambie Sorry for that, guess the community focus more on the linguistic discussions of French. I’ll contribute proper questions when diving into the study.

Comment: o need to apologize. Newbies aren't expected to know what the community focuses on, at first, right? :) The problem is never nouns. Problems arise with how verbs and nouns work differently in French.

Answer (score 11):

As somebody who has read mathematical French (although not that much of it, since nearly all math papers are in English these days), there are two things you need: (1) a rudimentary grasp of basic French vocabulary and grammar, and (2) knowledge of French mathematical terms.

The first you can get from any reasonable French course; there are some good ones online. Unless Bourbaki is written in much more flowery language than most French math papers are, you don't need that much French grammar and vocabulary; if you already know math, reading French math should be easier than reading most French novels. (I don't know of any French courses that are specialized for mathematics—you might have to learn a little more than you really need.)

For the second, one useful trick is to look up the French mathematical term in Wikipedia, and then click "English" under *langues*. For example, if you Google *"sommet mathématiques wikipédia"*, you get the article ["Sommet (géométrie)"](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sommet_(g%C3%A9om%C3%A9trie)) in French wikipédia. Clicking "English" under *langues* gives you the article "Vertex (geometry)" in Wikipedia, and you find that *un sommet* is *a vertex*, something that I think somebody who speaks both French and English but doesn't know mathematics could not have guessed.

Comment: As a native French speaking guy, I highly agree. This is exactly what I do when I want to write a post on [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/): I search for the words I learned in classes on Wikipedia and uses the English translation.

Comment: Got it. I suppose there is a similar way like to grab a math book written in French on a topic that I‘ve learned about, so that there’ll be large part of translation in head.

Answer (score 1):

It is often said, and agrees with my experience, that reading things like EGA is much easier than reading general French provided that your mathematical understanding is at an appropriate level.  The Bourbaki texts are thorough and systematic, so the early sections will certainly contain large chunks of material that you know already very well.  Often the mathematical symbols on their own will be sufficient for you to understand what they must be talking about, and that will enable you to guess what the words must mean, especially when a reasonable subset of the words are similar to their English counterparts.  As in English, there are quite a few stock phrases that occur very frequently in mathematical writing, and you will quickly come to recognize those.

It might actually be a rather interesting question in linguistics to analyse in detail the ways in which mathematical language is simpler than general language.

Comment: Yes, I found that comprehending fairly good percent of a text I’ve known very well in math could be easy, but the percentage wouldn’t be high enough for getting new information. Maybe I need some systematic studies.

Answer (score 0):

I have been confronted with this type of problems, when I did research and found a book on my topic in a language I didn't speak. There is no such thing as "mathematical French": it's French with specific mathematical vocabulary added. Bottom line is: you'll need to learn basic French (wherever and however) and spend a few months on that before you return to those books. I had to do the same in latin a few years ago; it didn't hinder my research and I got more benefits from that than trying to gain time by not learning.

Comment: Guess my problem lies in finding a balance between learning through a systematic study of grammar, syntax and all that, and learning through practice with the so-called “mathematical French” by reading a material I interested in using dictionary or whatever until I get every information needed. Either way needs a good amount of struggle.

Comment: This is not exactly true. As a translator, I often qualify the language: literary English, mathematical English, etc. The point though is that they are all subsets of the language itself, which is the set.